# Using collation in Linq to Sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

Imagine this sql query

```
select * from products order by name collate Persian_100_CI_AI asc
```

Now using Linq:

```
product = DB.Products.OrderBy(p => p.name); // what should I do here?
```

How can I apply collation?

Comment: I don't think this is possible using Linq-to-SQL. You can wrap your sql query in a view, then run a LINQ to SQL query against this view.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos my website is multi-language then for each select that uses collation I need a different view for each language and when a new language is added a new view for each select must be added. This doesn't look right

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani a stored procedure that uses a dynamic query (with Exec)?

Comment: @xanatos I'm new to Linq and the best reason for using linq was avoiding coding both side (sql and c#) but this way again I'll be creating stored procedures as before. however I want to learn how different things are done with Linq. then Its not possible to avoid stored procedures right?

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani If you need SQL-side pagination, or you have a WHERE that is based on collation, then Stored Procedure. Otherwise Gert Arnold's solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is now possible with EF Core 5.0 using the [collate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldbfunctionsextensions.collate) function.

In your example the code would be:

```
product = DB.Products.OrderBy(p => EF.Functions.Collate(p.name, "Persian_100_CI_AI"));
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no direct way.
Workaround:

Create function in Sql Server

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnsConvert]
    (
      @p NVARCHAR(2000) ,
      @c NVARCHAR(2000)
    )
RETURNS NVARCHAR(2000)
AS
    BEGIN
        IF ( @c = 'Persian_100_CI_AI' )
            SET @p = @p COLLATE Persian_100_CI_AI
        IF ( @c = 'Persian_100_CS_AI' )
            SET @p = @p COLLATE Persian_100_CS_AI

        RETURN @p    
    END
```

Import it in model and use:

```
from o in DB.Products
orderby DB.fnsConvert(s.Description, "Persian_100_CI_AI")
select o;
```

Comment: What is the type of DB?

Answer (score 4):

You can't change the collation through a LINQ statement. You better do the sorting in memory by applying a `StringComparer` that is initialized with the correct culture (at least... I hope it's correct) and ignores case (`true`).

```
DB.Products.AsEnumerable()
  .OrderBy (x => x, StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("fa-IR"), true))
```

**edit**

Since people (understandably) don't seem to read comments let me add that this is answered using the exact code of the question, in which there is no `Where` or `Select`. Of course I'm aware of the possibly huge data overhead when doing something like...

```
DB.Products.AsEnumerable().Where(...).Select(...).OrderBy(...)
```

...which first pulls the entire table contents into memory and then does the filtering and projection the database itself could have done by moving `AsEnumerable()`:

```
DB.Products.Where(...).Select(...).AsEnumerable().OrderBy(...)
```

The point is that if the database doesn't support ordering by some desired character set/collation the *only* option using EF's `DbSet` is to do the ordering in memory.

The alternative is to run a SQL query having an `ORDER BY` with explicit collation. If paging is used, this is the only option.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, yeah the cultureinfo is correct (fa-ir) but actually it was not important and I used it as an example I use many languages and I'll be passing a variable there : `new CultureInfo(language)`

Comment: And something would you advise this solution performance wise? and If there is a paging then It seems like I should just get all results and then implement pagination afterwards

Comment: Hey-hey, careful with this! `.AsEnumerable()` will return _all_ records and _than_ do the sorting

Comment: I think for performance it doesn't really make a great difference. Of course database engines have smart sorting algorithms and usually lots of resources, but the average client/host machine shouldn't be too impressed either.

Comment: @nZeus It's only about sorting. Any *filtering or projection* should of course be applied before the `AsEnumerable`.

Comment: Yeah I know but I'm considering the project in total and what I have to do next. as sorting has effect on filtering then It seems like I should use a stored procedure or view in general

Comment: That, or a table-valued function taking the collation code as parameter. Then indeed you can apply sorting and filtering in the same collation.

Comment: This solution is awful in many cases if you have a lot of data and you end up getting memory exception. It is always better to get what you need from sql, not inside memory.