# using COLLATE in Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I need to add Collation into `ORDER BY` clause. In other words, need to create **IQueryable** which will be interpteted something like:

```sql
SELECT column FROM table
ORDER BY [column] COLLATE *AnyCollation* DESC
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot change the collation using the LINQ. However there are some workarounds like creating a function in SQL Server and changing the collation there and then using it your code.

Here is a related thread which you can refer: [Using collation in Linq to Sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723053/using-collation-in-linq-to-sql)