# How do I use COLLATE based on a function in T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql, user-defined-functions, collate

I have the following function for setting COLLATE for the column @p based on the @c parameter. I was inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29723248/892251).

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnsConvert]
(
    @p NVARCHAR(2000),
    @c NVARCHAR(2000)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(2000)
AS
    BEGIN
        IF ( @c = 'sv-SE' )
            SET @p = @p COLLATE Finnish_Swedish_100_CI_AS
        ELSE 
            SET @p = @p COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
        RETURN @p    
    END
```

This is how I use it:

```
SELECT Title FROM Things
ORDER BY dbo.fnsConvert(Title, 'sv-SE')
```

Result: AÅÄBCÖ
Expected: ABCÅÄÖ

In an attempt to debug it I run

```
DECLARE @l nvarchar(255)
DECLARE @P nvarchar(255)
EXEC @l = dbo.fnsConvert
    @p = Test, @c = 'sv-SE';

SELECT @l
```

This just return the string Test. I would expect it to also contain the COLLATE statement but I could very well be wrong about that.

Comment: I think, that the linked answer you read before is not correct... A simple variable does not *know* its collation...

Comment: Scalar functions can't return a value with implied collation. The answer on your link is wrong as Shnugo said. You will have to do this with dynamic SQL as collations can't be parametrized.

Comment: collation is mode of comparison, not a property of string variables. `COLLATE` keyword implies collation used for comparison (and thus indexing)

Answer (score 1):

you should add collation to `order by`. Collation is type definition and you can not change it by a set operation.

```
SELECT Title FROM Things
ORDER BY Title COLLATE Finnish_Swedish_100_CI_AS
```