# Cannot resolve collation conflict, possible linq/EF solution per column?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

Attempting to insert new rows from a ASP.NET Core API with Entity Framework gives me this error:

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between \"SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS\" and \"SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS\" in the equal to operation.

I tried following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607560/cannot-resolve-the-collation-conflict-between-sql-latin1-general-cp1-ci-as-and) - and indeed, there is a different collation set on the columns for the tables.

Unfortunately we have been told we will not be allowed to alter the database (SQL Server) in any way. Is there any way to handle this per column when I insert the rows with EF (from the C# layer) so that it matches what the database expects? Or do I just have to tell the client "sorry, it's broken?" I'm not sure what to do at that point.

Comment: Are you using EF Core? Possibly you can do something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29723248/2557128) to create custom collation functions in the database to wrap the columns in EF.

Comment: @NetMage hmm... do you think it would work to have the collation function in a different database, brought in with a different connection string? Is that possible?

Comment: The connection string isn't relevant - remember, the query is translated to SQL and sent to the database engine for execution. If it is something you can do in SQL, it would work, but I don't think it would. Your only alternative would be to use `AsEnumerable` in your query to split the work between client and server, which could involve bringing lots of data to the client and be very, very slow.