# SQL Server Collation conflict in Georgian

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation

I have database working on Georgia server and database collation is `Georgian_Modern_Sort_CI_AS` so when I try to do some select on this database I cannot do select queries because of collation problem because my data include also latin alphabet unfortunately I cannot select `nvarchar` items.

What can I do for not getting collation error?

Comment: are you using temp tables?

Comment: @RedDevil nope i don't use

Answer (score 1):

you can change the collation on select with using `COLLATE` keyword.

```
SELECT *
  FROM MyTable
  where MyLatinColumn COLLATE Georgian_Modern_Sort_CI_AS = MyGeorgianColumn
```

Comment: Do you have any sugession for EntityFramework Linq queries?

Comment: you can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723053/using-collation-in-linq-to-sql